# Adding stuff to run on startup of Pharo Image

Tags: startup, smalltalk, pharo

I'd like to add stuff to run at the beginning of a pharo image start-up. Nothing fancy just a call to a class method that is an entry point to my application.
I can't find any guides to making smalltalk scripts at startup.
Alternatively are there any method which you can add stuff to be done at image startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squeak has a built-in mechanism that will notify selected classes that an image has just been launched. [This page](http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/209.html) explains how to do this. It should also work in Pharo.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what I'm looking for,For people looking at this at some point past 2010 it does look like they might change it in the future though(http://code.google.com/p/pharo/wiki/StartupAndShutdown).

Answer (score 4):

In Pharo 1.4 there is the StartupLoader class that will file in startup.st from the same directory as the image or all files from ~/.config/pharo/#{version} or ~/.config/pharo/general.

Currently the class comments and examples do not agree on which files StartupLoader should do so this could change, this works properly in Pharo 2.0

For a fuller description see this [blog](http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/startuploader-running-startup-scripts-in-pharo/)